React Native throughing an axios error 429
I was making a voice assisstant chatbot and come to an error of axios 429 (too many requests). I can't find a way of resolving this issue, I tried rate limiter still no success.
I am working with Expo go so please suggest according to expo development build.
This is my App.js File and I am hitting the apiCall function directly to the the function.
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import AppNavigation from "./src/navigation";
import { apiCall } from "./src/api/openai";

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    apiCall("What is magnet")
  });
  return <AppNavigation />;
}

Here is my openai.jsx file where I defined the api calling
import axios from "axios";
import { apiKey } from "../constants/data";

const client = axios.create({
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + apiKey,
    "content-type": "application/json",
  },
});

const chatgptEndpoint = "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions";
const dalleEndpoint = "https://api.openai.com/v1/images/generations";

export const apiCall = async (prompt, messages) => {    
  try {
    const res = await client.post(chatgptEndpoint, {
      model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
      messages: [
        {
          role: "user", 
          content: `Does this message want to generate AI picture, image, art or anything similar ? ${prompt}, Simply answer yes or no`,
        }
      ],
    });

    console.log("data : ", res.data);
    return res.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error: ", error);
    return Promise.resolve({ success: false, msg: error.message });
  }
};

Here is my screen from which I hit the request from user interaction.
import { View, Text, Image, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  widthPercentageToDP as wp,
  heightPercentageToDP as hp,
} from "react-native-responsive-screen";
import Features from "../components/Features";
import { dummyMessages } from "../constants/data";
import Voice from "@react-native-voice/voice";


// ##############################

export default function HomeScreen() {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState(dummyMessages);
  const [recording, setRecording] = useState(false);
  const [speaking, setSpeaking] = useState(false);
  const [result, setResult] = useState("");


  // Handlers 
  const speechStartHandler = (e) => {
    console.log("start handler speech");
  };

  const speechResultsHandler = (e) => {
    console.log("voice event", e);
    const text = e.value[0];
    setResult(text);
  };

  const speechEndHandler = (e) => {
    setRecording(false);
    console.log("End Handler Speech");
  };

  const speechErrorHandler = (e) => {
    console.log("error", e);
  };

  // Functions Onclick or OnPress
  const startRecording = async () => {
    setRecording(true);
    try {
      await Voice.start("en-US");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error ", error);
    }
  };

  const stopRecording = async () => {
    try {
      await Voice.stop();
      setRecording(false);  
      //fethc result from chat gp
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error ", error);
    }
  };

  const clear = () => {
    setMessages([]);
  };

  const stopSpeaking = () => {
    setSpeaking(false);
  };


  // useEffect HOOks
  useEffect(() => {
    Voice.onSpeechStart = speechStartHandler;
    Voice.onSpeechResults = speechResultsHandler;
    Voice.onSpeechEnd = speechEndHandler;
    Voice.onSpeechError = speechErrorHandler;

    return () => {
      Voice.destroy().then(Voice.removeAllListeners);
    };
  }, []);

  // console.log("results: ", result);
  
  // ####################
  
  return (
    <View className="flex-1 bg-white">
      <View className="flex-1 mx-5 my-10">
        {/* {Bot Icon} */}
        <View className="flex-row justify-center">
          <Image
            source={require("../../assets/chatbot.png")}
            style={{ width: wp(30), height: hp(15) }}
          />
        </View>

        {/* {Features and Messages} */}
        {messages.length > 0 ? (
          <View className="space-y-2 flex-1">
            <Text
              style={{ fontSize: wp(5) }}
              className="text-gray-700 font-semibold ml-1"
            >
              Assistant
            </Text>
            <View
              style={{ height: hp(60) }}
              className="bg-gray-200 rounded-3xl p-4 "
            >
              <ScrollView
                bounces={false}
                className="space-y-4"
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
              >
                {messages.map((message, index) => {
                  if (message.role == "assistant") {
                    if (message.content.includes("https")) {
                      //image hai
                      return (
                        <View key={index} className="flex-row justify-start">
                          <View calssName="p-2 rounded-2xl bg-gray-300 rounded-tl-none">
                            <Image
                              source={{ uri: message.content }}
                              calssName="rounded-2xl"
                              resizeMode="contain"
                              style={{ height: hp(60), width: wp(60) }}
                            />
                          </View>
                        </View>
                      );
                    } else {
                      return (
                        //Content Hai
                        <View key={index} className="flex-row justify-start">
                          <View
                            style={{ width: wp(70) }}
                            className="bg-gray-300  rounded-xl rounded-tl-none p-2"
                          >
                            <Text> {message.content}</Text>
                          </View>
                        </View>
                      );
                    }
                  } else {
                    return (
                      <View key={index} className="flex-row justify-end">
                        <View
                          style={{ width: wp(70) }}
                          className="bg-white rounded-xl rounded-tr-none p-2"
                        >
                          <Text> {message.content}</Text>
                        </View>
                      </View>
                    );
                  }
                })}
              </ScrollView>
            </View>
          </View>
        ) : (
          <Features />
        )}
        {/* {Recording, clear, stop Message} */}
        <View className="flex justify-center items-center">
          {recording ? (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={stopRecording}>
              {/* Stop recording Button */}
              <Image
                style={{ width: wp(15), height: hp(12) }}
                source={require("../../assets/Sound Beat.gif")}
                calssName="rounded-full"
              ></Image>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ) : (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={startRecording}>
              {/* Start Recording Button */}
              <Image
                style={{ width: wp(13), height: hp(10) }}
                source={require("../../assets/mic.png")}
                calssName="rounded-full"
              ></Image>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}

          {messages.length > 0 && (
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={clear}
              className="bg-neutral-400 rounded-3xl p-3 absolute right-10"
            >
              <Text calssName="text-white font-semibold">Clear</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}

          {speaking && (
            <TouchableOpacity
              className="bg-neutral-400 rounded-3xl p-3 absolute left-10"
              onPress={stopSpeaking}
            >
              <Text calssName="text-white font-semibold">Stop</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}



Here's an updated version of your openai.jsx file that includes a simple rate limiter using axios-rate-limit package:
import axios from 'axios';
import { apiKey } from '../constants/data';
import rateLimit from 'axios-rate-limit';

const client = axios.create({
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' apiKey,
    'content-type': 'application/json',
  },
});

const chatgptEndpoint = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions';
const dalleEndpoint = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/images/generations';

const rateLimiter = rateLimit(client, {
  maxRequests: 5, // adjust this value based on OpenAI's rate limits
  perMilliseconds: 60000, // 1 minute
});

export const apiCall = async (prompt, messages) => {
  try {
    const res = await rateLimiter.post(chatgptEndpoint, {
      model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
      messages: [
        {
          role: 'user',
          content: `Does this message want to generate AI picture, image, art or anything similar? ${prompt}, Simply answer yes or no`,
        },
      ],
    });

    console.log('data : ', res.data);
    return res.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error: ', error);
    return Promise.resolve({ success: false, msg: error.message });
  }
};

You can use the axios-retry package to implement a retry mechanism :  https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-retry
